# Unable to pull the images in docker on Windows

Tags: docker, docker-compose, boot2docker

I have installed boot2docker in my windows 7 64 bit box (Docker Version: 1.3.0). But I'm not able to pull any public images, and it shows the below error message.

> Command :docker pull java.
>
> **Result:**
>
> Pulling repository java.
>
> Could not reach any registry endpoint.

But, I can able to perform other command successfully. Like Search, List of installed images (In my case it's 0).

Can somebody help me to overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you actually running Docker version 1.3.0? This version is likely way too old to interact with the newest Docker registry endpoint. Please try upgrading boot2docker (or better yet, upgrade to Docker Machine, Docker for Windows, or Docker Toolbox).

Comment: @Andy - I tried the same. And It works fine now. thank you.